# Identifying the PID of Vim 8.1 internal terminal launched with :terminal ++close

Tags: vimrc, terminal-buffer, linux-ubuntu, shell

When launching an internal Vim 8.1 terminal for an exclusive program like in `terminal ++close ipython`, is there a way to identify from vimscript which is the PID of the launched process (i.e. of the IPython launched) so I can use that information?

Retrieving that upon launching and after that are both of interest to me, in case they happen to differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the term_getjob() function to get the Job associated
with a terminal. You can then use the job_info() function to query the
"process" attribute of the job.

```
let job = term_getjob(5)
echo job_info(job).process
```